# What equation to use when finding 6 variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'm programming an application which will need to calculate and invert 6 variables.

e.g.

[4][20][15][16][0][1] -> (perform calculation) -> 450

450 -> (perform calculation) -> [4][20][15][16][0][1]

What would be the best direction to go to calculate and invert the calculation for these variables or nth variables if I wish to expand later on? I was looking at Matrices, linear equations, etc, but not sure the best and easiest method for programmatically making this a bidirectional equation. Edit: I’m looking to get the smallest number possible, and the range is 0 to 55 for my variables.

Comment: Depending on what restrictions you have this might not be possible, it might be impractical, or it might be outright boring.  You need to be especially careful that what you do can actually be reversed... that the function you are using is bijective (*or at least injective*) so that you can uniquely go from the result to the inputs.  A truly boring way would be if for instance your inputs were all whole numbers from $0$ to $99$ in which case you could just append leading zeroes to smaller numbers and concatenate them... so $f(4,20,15,16,0,1) = 042015160001$ for instance.

Comment: I’m more than happy with boring! I’m just looking to get the smallest number possible, and the range is 0 to 55 for my variables.

Comment: Now... that example I gave is hardly useful... you'd be better off just keeping it as a list rather than performing that calculation.  There is no benefit to having made that change.  Now... if you allow your inputs to be anything, this clearly doesn't work any more... but we can prove that such a reversible function can *not* be accomplished using matrices or linear equations.  It is a standard result from linear algebra.  Learn about it in a course there.  Now... if you were to ignore linearity as a requirement, we *can* have a bijection $\Bbb N^n\to \Bbb N$

Comment: The textbook example for pairs of positive integers mapping to positive integers would be $(a,b)\mapsto 2^{a-1}(2b-1)$, and this same idea can be extended to many pairs.  Now... you replied that you do have a limited range for each... My example in the first comment was effectively "*writing the number in base 100*", since you have range $0$ to $55$ for your inputs, you can just write your number in base $56$, but again I stress that this really is hardly useful.  All it is in the end is effectively removing the commas between numbers in the list or putting them back (*after relabeling*).

Comment: Would you mind writing an example as an answer and explain like I am 5 because I don’t do positive integer mapping very often lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 6 variables $x_0, \ldots, x_5$ all in the range $0 - 55$ you could form
$$n = x_0 + 56 x_1 + 56^2 x_2 + \cdots + 56^5 x_5.$$
To revert to the variables you can do (pseudocode):

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
i = 0
while n > 0 {
  x[i] = n % 56
  n := floor(n / 56)     # integer division
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the variables you have had the range $0$-$9$, i.e. single digits. In that case you could obviously append them to form a single 6-digit number.

To do that in a computer program, appending a digit $d$ to a number $t$ is done by calculating $10t+d$. The multiplication by $10$ shifts it to the left by appending a zero, and then adding $d$ sets the last digit to $d$. So you can simply do this six times in a loop, appending the six variables to zero.

You'll also want to extract the digits one by one. You can get the last digit of a number $t$ by evaluating $t \bmod 10$, which is $t\%10$ in some computer languages. Once you have that digit $d$, you can calculate $\frac{t-d}{10}$, removing the digit and shifting it to the right, so that you can then access the next digit.

In your case you have variables in the range $0$ to $55$ instead of $0$ to $9$. Therefore you should use $56$ at every spot I used $10$ in the above explanation. It may be easier to implement it base 10 first, so that it is easy to see that it works the way you want to before changing it to base 56.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do see the benefit of this approach, however, I am looking at trying to find a smaller or fraction and this seems to increase the size of it during the calculation so I'll see if anyone else has other answers.

Comment: @Rich Since there are $56^6$ possible sets of values the six variable can have, if you convert it to a unique single integer you cannot do better than an integer with a range of 0 to $56^6-1$. If you convert it anything with a smaller number of distinct values, the mapping will no longer be unique and the original variable values cannot be unambiguously recovered. Converting it to a floating point number is prone to rounding errors.